# !flag has two meanings in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, not-operator

```
boolean flag = false;
if(!flag) System.out.println(!flag); // prints true
```

I wonder why `!flag` being considered as `false` when it's a conditional parameter passed to `if statement` and as `true` elsewhere?

Comment: !flag should evaluate to true, everywhere.  what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not. `if (boolean expression) { statement }` means "execute the `statement` if `boolean expression` is true." Since `flag = false`, `!flag == true`. Always.

Comment: `execute the statement if boolean expression is true` this is what I was need to know. Thanks @dlev :)

Answer (score 2):

`!flag` where `flag` is `false` evaluates to `true` in all contexts, including if statements.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are probably misinterpreting the evaluation of conditional operator. The `if` operator performs the statements inside, if and only if the condition is evaluated as `true`.

Now, `flag` is equal to `false`. This means that negation of `flag` will be `true` (`!false = true`). This is why tne statement inside the if confition is performed and writes `true` (the negated value of `flag`) to your console output.

Answer (score 2):

`!flag` does not *change* the value of `flag`, it merely negates it when *evaluating* it.

Since `flag = false`, `!flag` is identical to `!false` which is `true`.
Your code is equivalent to this:

```
if (!false) System.out.println(!false);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (true) System.out.println(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in human language:

if flag is not true, print out the opposite value of "flag"