# Check for escape character in Java

Tags: java, char, escaping

I have a flat comma separated file that has `"\N"` for some rows. I need to load all rows and skip all those are not containing `\N`.
I am trying to do the following but it doesn't work.

```
if (!line.contains("\\N")) {
    //do load here
}
```

Above code still passes the line from csv below:

```
1,text,abc,\N,23,56
```

and then we have NumberFormatException (it should be Int Value there).
Why is this happening?

Comment: *I need to load all rows and skip all those are not containing \N.* You mean those **containing** \N, right?

Comment: Please put up a [mcve]

Comment: Please add more code that you have done so that we can help you with the problem.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Are you sure you debugged the error correctly?

Comment: @Overt_Agent On the contrary. Since `\N` is not a special character, the backslash literal needs to be escaped.

Comment: @shmosel Quite correct. This should be working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only process file lines that contain a **\N** then omit the **!** (exclamation) character from your **if** statement condition. This is the **NOT** flag.

What your condition is basically saying right now is:

> If the current text file line contained within the string variable
>   **line** does NOT contain a **\N** then do execute the code within the **if** statement block.

**IF** statements are only executed if the supplied condition is boolean **true**. Applying the ! flag basically sets the condition to **true** if the supplied condition is **NOT true**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658511/flag-has-two-meanings-in-java) may help you more.

If you want just those lines that DO contain a **\N** then your code should look like:

```
if (line.contains("\\N")) {
    //process line here
}
```

If you **DO NOT** want to process those file lines that contain **\N** then what you are using right now **should** work just fine.

Regarding your question:

> and then we have NumberFormatException (it should be Int Value there).
>   Why is this happening?

**\n** (lowercase n) is generally a tag which is applied within a string to force a New Line when processed, if a uppercase N is used it does not do this. In general, a lot of CSV files use the **\N** to mean **NULL** and others simply place nothing, just the delimiter. You will need to look into what is creating the CSV file to find the actual reason as to **why** since they may be using it for something else but for now you can consider it as **NULL**. Integer variables are never Null, they would be considered as containing 0 by default so you could change your code to:

```
if (line.contains("\\N") { line = line.replace("\\N", "0"); }
```

You could however also encounter **\N** where there should be a String so the above line will do you no good. One solution would be to handle **\N** within the contents of each array element (should it be there) after you have split the file line, for example:

```
String csvFilePath = "MyCSVfile.txt"; // assuming file is in classpath
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MyCSVfile.txt"))) {
    int j = 0; //used as a counter
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        j++; //increment counter
        String[] data = line.split(",");
        //if the ID value contains null then apply the counter (j) value.
        int id = Integer.parseInt(data[0].replace("\\N",String.valueOf(j)));
        String type = data[1].replace("\\N","");
        String text = data[2].replace("\\N","");
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(data[3].replace("\\N","0"));
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(data[4].replace("\\N","0"));
        int value3 = Integer.parseInt(data[5].replace("\\N","0"));
        System.out.println("ID is:\t\t" + id + "\nData Type is:\t" + type + 
                           "\nText is:\t" + text + "\nValue 1 is:\t" + value1 + 
                           "\nValue 2 is:\t" + value2 + "\nValue 3 is:\t" + 
                           value3 + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
} 
catch (IOException ex) { 
    //however you want to handle exception
}
```

This will handle the **\N** tag regardless of where it is encountered within any one of your CSV file lines.

Comment: It is never a good idea to print an exception’s message.  Messages often make no sense without the context of the exception class, and many exceptions have no message at all.  Always do `ex.printStackTrace();` or send the exception to a logger method which will log the stack trace.

Comment: @VGR - Good point...I didn't realize that the IOException didn't happen to have an exception that "did not" give a reasonable message.